# How to determine the width I can use in a table

Tags: tables

I have a table of fixed width in which I want to put some thing such as a figure or another box. But the problem is that I can't determine the width of the object that I want to put in the table. I have tried using the width of the table, but it seems that the table doesn't like this(maybe the width available in a table is less than that of the table itself) and it broke just as following:
[image]

By the way I'd like to let this table to extend to the end of the page, even though there may be some blank area in the bottom of the table. Just as Microsoft Word in which I can define the size of table by my self without warring about alignment and anything else. If someone has another idea to do this, please tell me. Thank you in advance!
And here is my code:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|C|c|C|c|C|}
  \hline
  Name &Richard &Class &1112101 &NO. &1111200117\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{
  \parbox{\textwidth}{Some text}
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Could you add the code you used to make your error above? Your question is pretty difficult to answer right now; we just have to guess what you need.

Comment: "Sir, I have a cunning plan.  If you make it less wide, it will fit!"

Comment: @Ryan Now I have uploaded my code, could you help find out the problem?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes But I don't know what width to use so that it looks perfect, since the size of the table may changes. What I need is a way to determine the width I can use in a table without manually tweak it.

Comment: I am sorry Richard for playing a verbal trick on you, but based on the content contained in your example table, I tried to reprise the famous line of Baldrick used throughout the many episodes of Black Adder, in which he proclaimed a "cunning plan" that was, in fact, useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `p`aragraph-column of fixed width that removes the column separation and rule widths (two of each in this case):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,lipsum}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|C|c|C|c|C|}
  \hline
  Name & Richard & Class & 1112101 & NO. & 1111200117 \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{6}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{%
    \lipsum*[2]% Some text

    \rule{0pt}{10\baselineskip}% Vertical strut
    } \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

A vertical strut at the end of the cell pushes the horizontal rule downward, leaving some empty space.

Comment: Beat me to it. Need to compensate for the two column separators.

Comment: Since the `array` package is loaded, one also needs to subtract `2\arrayrulewidth` to obtain the available width of the `p` column.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: **@Mico Below has the right answer, taking the rule width into account.**

So I've spent the last 15 mins thinking about this and I can't work it out.

Using @Werner's solution, which I agree should be the right answer, I get little gaps along the edge of the table.

By trial and error, I get the correct size of the paragraph dimension as \textwidth-12.7995pt, to as many decimals as I can still see a difference by zooming in (who knows if my pdf renderer is actually this accurate). Werner's solution of 2\tabcolsep = 12.0pt (when set to default article). Does anyone know why there's this discrepancy of .7995pt?

Here's the difference, mine on top, Werner's below:

[image]

And the MWE: (now including Mico's answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{Mico's Correct Answer:}\\\\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|C|c|C|c|C|}
    \hline
    Name &Richard &Class &1112101 &NO. &1111200117\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{%
    \lipsum*[2]
    }\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\vspace\baselineskip\\
\noindent
My Estimated Solution:\\\\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|C|c|C|c|C|}
    \hline
    Name &Richard &Class &1112101 &NO. &1111200117\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|p{\textwidth-12.7995pt}|}{
    \lipsum*[2]
    }\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\vspace\baselineskip\\
\noindent
Werner's Initial Solution\\\\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|C|c|C|c|C|}
    \hline
    Name & Richard & Class & 1112101 & NO. & 1111200117 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{%
        \lipsum*[2]% Some text

        \rule{0pt}{10\baselineskip}% Vertical strut
        } \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

why isn't 2\tabcolsep lining up perfectly?

Comment: Each vertical rule has width `0.4pt`. The default value of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt`. `2\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth=12.8pt`. Werner's table is actually *too wide* by `0.8pt`.

Comment: @Mico the lines themselves, I didn't think of that. Thanks! Its a shame the right answer is down in a comment on the lower-voted answer.

Comment: I just upvoted yours. Please edit your code, though, to eliminate the `\parbox` inside the multicolumn of type `p`: The `p` column type *constructs* `\parbox`es -- no need to double up...

Comment: @Mico Oops, when I was working on this I had four tables with the different ways of doing it and was checking if that made a difference, Looks like I kept the wrong table. Thanks.